# What events fire when the Windows Phone 8 Map control starts and stops scrolling?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, maps, bing-maps

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for a while now and I don't seem to be getting anywhere. I want to stop a timer when the user starts scrolling and start it when the user stops. I've tried using the Manipulation events but those don't seem to fire at all. Does anyone know what the events are that I need to hook into, or if there is a better approach to this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The events aren't fired as `Map` intercepts them (similar situation will be with Pivot control). If you want to be notified when the user had touched the screen and performed for example a FreeDrag gesture, you can use [Touch.FrameReported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.input.touch.framereported%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) event and [TouchPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827740.aspx):

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.FreeDrag;
    Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
}

private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
    if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable) // check only dragging 
    {
        // get point relative to Viewport
        TouchPoint mainTouch = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(yourMap);
        // drag started Key - down
        if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Down)
           timer.Stop();

        // check if drag has completed (key up)
        if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Up)
        {
            timer.Start();
            // in both cases you can use some other Properties of TouchPoint
            // do something for example dependant on coordinates 
            // double x = mainTouch.Position.X;
            // double y = mainTouch.Position.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that as you have coordinates relative to your Map, you can check if the User had touched the screen within the area of the Map (relative coordinates and Map dimensions).

Comment: @CAMOBAP You are welcome. The method gives quite nice possibilities as it's 'independet' from UIControls. Thought it sometimes needs some 'tuning'.